# Minimum value of a column corresponding to another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data table below that I am pulling from a data base

```
  type   week  amount
    a   201304  77
    a   201304  77
    a   201304  77
    a   201304  77
    a   201304  71
    a   201304  71
    a   201305  77
    a   201305  77
    a   201305  77
    a   201305  77
    a   201305  77
    a   201305  77
```

I am trying to pull only the minimum value from the `amount` column for every week only, so that table should be like this

```
  type   week  amount
    a   201304  71
    a   201305  77
```

Thank you for you help

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question*). Please also include a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with this regular `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT type, week, MIN(amount) amount
FROM table_name
GROUP BY type, week
```

## EDIT

If you have different types in the same week with the same amount, what do you want to do? If you want to know what type has the MIN(amount) in a week:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.*
FROM
 (SELECT week, MIN(amount) amount
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY week) t1
  JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.amount = t2. amount AND t1.week = t2.week
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Select type, week, amount 
from
    (Select type, week, amount, row_number () over(partition by week, amount order by amount asc) as rownumber
     from table_name)
where rownumber = 1
```

What this does is assign row numbers to your partition of just week and amount. You may have many amounts per week. This numbers them and you sort them so that the smallest will be on top (row 1). You get just this row in the where clause. This will produce a minimum amount per week regardless of type.

Comment: you can't use rownumber in the where clause as SQL will not understand the alias at the time the result set is calculated.  Also, window functions cannot be used in where clause either. you can however select from your select as a sub select or common table expression

Comment: @Matt thanks for the guidance. I edited my answer. Kindly let me know if anything incorrect remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a min and in clause

```
 select * from my_table 
 where (amount, week ) in (
    select min(amount), week from my_table group by week 
 );
```